# How to allow access to my apache webserver through comodo firewall

Tags: apache, configuration, firewall

Can anyone explain me how I can allow access to my apache webserver through the comodo firewall?

I am a newbie to firewall configuration, so a quiet detailed explanation or a link to a good tutorial/example would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a moment to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho this is a old question but i came across this today and since i have already figured this out and thought maybe it could help someone too:
To fix this i had to add a rule in the firewall's `Global Rules` section to allow incoming connections for port 80. Also if you are behind a router don't forget to forward the port 80 to your local ip too.